# Laravel: creating a hasManyThrough function with respect to a pivot table

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

Struggling to come up with the right relation for my scenario. Here is what I have:

`Dealer.php`

```
    public function questions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Question::class, 'dealer_question')
            ->orderBy('order_column')
            ->withPivot('alternate_label');
    }
```

`Question.php`

```
    public function section()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\Section::class);
    }

    public function dealers(): \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Models\Dealer::class, 'dealer_question');
    }
```

`Section.php`

```
    public function questions(): \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\Question::class, 'section_id')
            ->orderBy('order_column');
    }
```

Here is my brief database schema:

dealers table:
id, name, url, etc

dealer_question table:
dealer_id, question_id

questions table:
id, label, section_id, etc

sections:
id, label, etc

I'm trying to come up with a `sections()` relation inside my `Dealer` model. The function would first find all the dealer's questions and from them, determine all the sections.

Comment: I think hasManyThrough only works if you have two 1-many relationships that share one model. I don't think it works when a many-to-many is involved